# How can I import a specific method of a module which both are given by inputs

Tags: python

```
My_Module=input() 
My_Method=input()
from My_Module import My_Method
```

I'm writing a program and I need to import a method first.
But when I type what I did in above it sends an error and says can't "`import name My_Method from My_Module`".

I tried 2 other different codes but they didn't work either.I know that `My_Method` is a name and can't be imported but what can I do to solve this problem and have it worked?

Comment: So are you trying to input say `math` and `factorial` and have your code import `math.factorial`?

Comment: yes.But because factorial is given by an input it sends back an error that it's a name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) to get the module in a dynamic way (using a variable content as name)

Then, you need to use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to get the function within the module.

```
import importlib

modulename = input('module ')
funcname = input('func ')

mod = importlib.import_module(modulename)
func = getattr(mod, funcname)

print(func)
# call the function
func()
```

*Thx to [Patrick Haugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6779307/patrick-haugh) and his comment*

Comment: As the documentation for `__import__` notes, you should prefer the use of [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module)

Comment: @jason I updated it according to the last comment. Use this version, it's better and fix some issues